# Umbraco CMS can't save template

Tags: umbraco, savechanges

I'v set up a new umbraco project in visual studio, with any preinstalled templates, when i am trying to add new masterpage i can't save it, i can edit it in visual studio but i cant save any change in umbraco backend.
Any sugestion to solve my problem ?

Answer (score 5):

Its probably a permissions problem. Make sure IIS has r/w permissions to the directory where you are saving the masterpages